# Best way of joining many time series in pandas to a single datetime index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am reading many CSV files. Each one contains time series data. For example:

```
import pandas as pd

csv_a = [['2019-05-25 10:00', 25, 60],
         ['2019-05-25 10:05', 26, 25],
         ['2019-05-25 10:10', 27, 63],
         ['2019-05-25 10:20', 28, 62]]
df_a = pd.DataFrame(csv_a, columns=["Timestamp", "Temperature", "Humidity"])
df_a["Timestamp"] = (pd.to_datetime(df_a["Timestamp"]))

csv_b = [['2019-05-25 10:05', 1020],
         ['2019-05-25 10:10', 1021],
         ['2019-05-25 10:15', 1019],
         ['2019-05-25 10:45', 1035]]
df_b = pd.DataFrame(csv_b, columns=["Timestamp", "Pressure"])
df_b["Timestamp"] = (pd.to_datetime(df_b["Timestamp"]))
```

After creating these Dataframes, we can see:

```
print(df_a)
            Timestamp  Temperature  Humidity
0 2019-05-25 10:00:00           25        60
1 2019-05-25 10:05:00           26        25
2 2019-05-25 10:10:00           27        63
3 2019-05-25 10:20:00           28        62

print(df_b)
            Timestamp  Pressure
0 2019-05-25 10:05:00      1020
1 2019-05-25 10:10:00      1021
2 2019-05-25 10:15:00      1019
3 2019-05-25 10:45:00      1035
```

I want to create a new Dataframe with a regular index, for example:

```
import datetime as dt

start = dt.datetime(2019,5,25,10,0,0)
end = dt.datetime(2019,5,25,10,20,0)
index = pd.date_range(start, end, freq='5min')
```

And then, start appending each time series in different columns, filling the missing values with NaN and discarting values out of my index.

Desired output:

```
                     Temperature  Humidity  Pressure
Timestamp                                           
2019-05-25 10:00:00         25.0      60.0       NaN
2019-05-25 10:05:00         26.0      25.0    1020.0
2019-05-25 10:10:00         27.0      63.0    1021.0
2019-05-25 10:15:00          NaN       NaN    1019.0
2019-05-25 10:20:00         28.0      62.0       NaN
```

And I also want do this as efficient as possible. Let's say I have hundreds of CSVs and long series.

I am messing with Panda's functions like concat or append, but I am not able to obtain what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand you already had a custom datetimeindex `index` and want to join each time series by this `index`. Try `combine_first` and `reindex`. If you have multiple time series to join, you need to use loop or use python `reduce`

```
df_out = df_b.combine_first(df_a).reindex(index)

Out[1063]:
                     Humidity  Pressure  Temperature
2019-05-25 10:00:00      60.0       NaN         25.0
2019-05-25 10:05:00      25.0    1020.0         26.0
2019-05-25 10:10:00      63.0    1021.0         27.0
2019-05-25 10:15:00       NaN    1019.0          NaN
2019-05-25 10:20:00      62.0       NaN         28.0
```

---

If your time series don't have the same column names, you may try `join`. Just list the time series inside the bracket `[]`

```
df_out = df_a.join([df_b], how='outer').reindex(index)

Out[1068]:
                     Temperature  Humidity  Pressure
2019-05-25 10:00:00         25.0      60.0       NaN
2019-05-25 10:05:00         26.0      25.0    1020.0
2019-05-25 10:10:00         27.0      63.0    1021.0
2019-05-25 10:15:00          NaN       NaN    1019.0
2019-05-25 10:20:00         28.0      62.0       NaN
```

Comment: @ansev: This line of his description `...discarting values out of my index...` makes impression that he joins dataframes base on pre-define index. I may be wrong though :)

Comment: This solution works for me :D I can attach everything using a loop of `join` and then trim it with `reindex`. I didn't know the `combine_first` method, it's really useful if you have many pieces of the same series. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html). You could check with [`Series.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) 
to discard rows where there is a temporary jump greater than the period.
But you could choose another criteria to exclude rows (let me know if you want to choose another criteria)

```
df2 = (df_a.merge(df_b, on='Timestamp', how='outer')
           .sort_values('Timestamp'))
diff=df2['Timestamp'].diff().abs().bfill()
mask=diff.eq(diff.min())
new_df=(df2.loc[mask]
           .set_index('Timestamp')
       )
print(new_df)


#                     Temperature  Humidity  Pressure
#Timestamp                                           
#2019-05-25 10:00:00         25.0      60.0       NaN
#2019-05-25 10:05:00         26.0      25.0    1020.0
#2019-05-25 10:10:00         27.0      63.0    1021.0
#2019-05-25 10:15:00          NaN       NaN    1019.0
#2019-05-25 10:20:00         28.0      62.0       NaN
```

---

You could **select the frecuency** 
and rule out those who don't comply by doing

```
df2 = (df_a.merge(df_b, on='Timestamp', how='outer')
           .set_index('Timestamp')
        )

new_df=(df2.reindex(pd.date_range(df2.index.min(),df2.index.max(),freq='5min'))
           .loc[lambda x: x.isna().all(axis=1).cumsum().eq(0)])
```

or simply enter the lower and upper limit statically as you say in your question

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `pd.merge`?

```
pd.merge(df_a, df_b, how='outer').set_index('Timestamp').sort_index()
```

output:

```
                     Temperature  Humidity  Pressure
Timestamp                                           
2019-05-25 10:00:00         25.0      60.0       NaN
2019-05-25 10:05:00         26.0      25.0    1020.0
2019-05-25 10:10:00         27.0      63.0    1021.0
2019-05-25 10:15:00          NaN       NaN    1019.0
2019-05-25 10:20:00         28.0      62.0       NaN
2019-05-25 10:45:00          NaN       NaN    1035.0
```

Comment: please don't copy solution

Comment: @ansev I don't want to argue about this, but I just think we crossed answers for the question within a couple of minutes. Moreover, it is only a merge not anything complex to be copied and branded as a solution. If so, I should say that all copied from the python documentation. :)